# How accept date and display the date in dd/mm format using the input type=date in html without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am working with angular and want to accept date from user the format of the date should be dd/mm and not include the year and the calender which is diplayed on click of date field shoul also not include the year

e.g : [as the image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvnAQ.png)
How can I achieve this without using jquery

Comment: What are you using as a calendar input? JqueryUI?

Comment: input type="date"

Comment: The _display format_ of `<input type="date">` is dependent on the user's locale; and you can't make it not include the year. You will need to use some sort of custom datepicker library here.

Comment: Which libraries can i use and achieve this ?